# What is the difference between the Azure Storage BlobClient and BlockBlobClient in v12 .NET SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I've looked around but can't seem to find anywhere in docs and the Intellisense documentation for these APIs is nearly identical.

What is the difference between an Azure Storage `BlockBlobClient` and a `BlobClient` in the Azure Storage v12 SDK?

Which one should I be using for efficiently uploading file streams to Azure Blob Storage using the Azure Storage v12 .NET SDK?

Is there any difference between these two bits of code and how they get files up to the cloud??

```cs
var container = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

var blobClient = container.GetBlobClient(filename); // this?
var blockBlockClient = container.GetBlockBlobClient(filename); // or this?
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Azure Blob Storage supports three kinds of blobs - [`Block, Page and Append`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction#blobs). While a lot of operations are common for all of these blobs (like delete, copy, lease etc.), there are some operations which are specific to a blob type (like put block, put block list for block blobs). To see operations specific to a particular blob type, please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/operations-on-blobs.

[`BlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient?view=azure-dotnet) provides functionality which can be used for all kinds of blobs.

However to deal with functionality only available with specific kind of blob, you will need to use a client specific for that e.g. [`BlockBlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blockblobclient?view=azure-dotnet) to deal with block blobs, [`AppendBlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.appendblobclient?view=azure-dotnet) to deal with append blobs and [`PageBlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.pageblobclient?view=azure-dotnet) to deal with page blobs.

Comment: Thanks for the info and links, @gaurav.  It would be nice if the Intellisense/docs included this bit of clarification as well....

Comment: SDK documentation does mention this. First line [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blockblobclient?view=azure-dotnet) is `The BlockBlobClient allows you to manipulate Azure Storage block blobs.`. However I do agree with you. IMHO, there should be a user guide which should tell you when to use what kind of class.

Comment: I ended up here looking for the conceptual differences between block, page and append blobs. This page was helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs

Answer (score 4):

BlockBlobClient is a specialization - when you know you're dealing with only block blobs, you can use this. It will have some special functions which will only apply for block blobs. More functionality.

BlobClient is a generic implementation - all its functions can be safely executed on any blob type - block/append/page. Less functionality.

In your case you can use either. They both have the functions you will need.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.  I'll probably just use the specialized one, since I'm only dealing with block blobs.